# Show Hidden Div While Hover an Image which is inside Table with CSS only

Tags: html, css-tables

I am working on a table based website and want to show a DIV when hover an image which is inside table. This is my fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Anthony12/bv57r9bs/

Div is not showing when hovering. Please solve it.

My HTML

```
<div id="Layer1" class="mydiv">
<strong><font color="#FFFFFF">This is image Descriptions.</font></strong>
```

My CSS

```
.image:hover + .mydiv {
visibility: visible;}
#myimage:hover {
opacity: 1;
}
#myimage {
opacity: 0.4;
} 
.mydiv{
visibility: hidden; 
position:absolute; 
left:583px; 
top:318px; 
width:153px; 
height:192px; 
z-index:2; 
background-color: #CC3300; 
border: 2px solid #000000;"}
```

Comment: You can't do this with CSS; first: it would involve a parent-selector (CSS doesn't have one), and second: it would require a previous-sibling selector (CSS doesn't have one).

Comment: is this what you look for : http://jsfiddle.net/bv57r9bs/6/ add some style :http://jsfiddle.net/bv57r9bs/7/ ?

Comment: `<font color="#FFFFFF">` is deprecated (old and not used anymore) and not needed. Specify the color in the CSS. Something like `.mydiv { color: #FFF; )`

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by using a child selector if you place the hidden div inside the parent element. In this case though, you want an image shown, so your going to have to set the image to be a background image of the parent element.

```
<td height="275" align="center" class="image" 
    style="background-image: url(http://www.gratisography.com/pictures/122.jpg);">

    <div class="desc">
        Laborum fugiat legam tempor varias ad tamen mandaremus si exercitation
    </div>

</td>

.image {
    opacity: 0.4;
    background-size: cover;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
} 

.desc{
    opacity: 0;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#fff;
    color:#333;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

I'm setting the position of the TD element to relative so that the 'desc' child element can use absolute positioning to place it at the bottom of its parent element. I also using "background-size: cover;" so that the image we're using covers the entire background of the TD.

```
.image:hover {
   opacity: 1;
}

.image:hover > .desc{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

After adding the hover for the image (parent), we add in a child selector to set the inside element's opacity and visibility. Using opacity, you can do css3 transitions so that you can make the transition into view look good. If you set the parent element's overflow to hidden, you could also make it pop into view from the bottom of the element.

http://jsfiddle.net/bv57r9bs/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `div` just after `image` like this:

```
<img class="myimage" id="myimage" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjE5MTQ3NjUyMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDA5MDE3Nw@@._V1_SX105_CR0,0,105,105_AL_.jpg" width="113" height="114">
<div id="mydiv" class="mydiv">
    <strong><font color="#FFFFFF">This is image Descriptions.</font></strong>
</div>
```

And it will works as you want.

**[Check Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bv57r9bs/5/)**

Otherwise it's not possible using only pure CSS and you have to use Javascript and `JQuery` because `CSS` doesn't have previous selector or parent selector or somthing like this.

Note: your JSFiddle has some issue too, your image class must be named as `myimage` instead of `image`.